# iframe disable hyperlinks in pdf - IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have stuck with this from yesterday and unable to find solution so decided to ask question here.

I am using iframe to display my pdf file,
now the problem is pdf contains hyperlinks and that should not be clickable in IE in chrome I am able to disable pointer events using

```
pointer-events: none;
```

but this property can be used for svg elements only in IE so that is not working.
Thank you for your time.

```js
<script>
   function DisableFrameLinks(){
   alert('fn called');
     var myIFrame = document.getElementById("myFrameId1");
            var links = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
   alert(index);
                links[index].removeAttribute('href');
            }
 }
  </script>
```

```html
<body onload="DisableFrameLinks();"> 

<div>
<iframe id="myFrameId" style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="PDF in an i-Frame" src="D:/test1.pdf" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="1100" width="850" ></iframe>
</div>
<br>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

this works fine if I have html in my iframe but as I want pdf It's not working.

Comment: I wish it was duplicate buddy,<br> please read full question I have tried working around with link(<a> tag) but that's not helping.

Comment: hmm I believe you'll need to show the pdf by your own instead of relying on the browser using PDF.js or viewer.js, in that case this question will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053948/how-to-disable-hyperlinks-within-a-pdf-rendered-by-pdf-js

Comment: Really appreciate your help but I think in that question he uses pdf.js while i'm not. Thanks though.

Comment: I know that question uses PDF.js, I thought you could use it to show the pdf instead of showing it in an `iframe` :)