# Pdfs in QWebEngineView: How to select letters inside linked phrase

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I use `pyqt5 QWebEngineView` to display pdfs. In the pdfs there are phrases that are linked. When I want to select individual words or letters, it doesn't work with the links. Is there a possibility in `QWebEngineView` to "turn off" the links without changing the pdf itself?

The picture below shows an example: I can't select single letters in the linked phrase "Nichtamtliches Inhaltsverzeichnis". I can only select the whole phrase.

[image]

The code I use to display the pdf is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings, QWebEngineView
import sys

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        webView = QWebEngineView()
        webView.settings().setAttribute(
            QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        webView.settings().setAttribute(
            QWebEngineSettings.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
        webView.load(QUrl.fromUserInput("path-to-pdf"))
        self.setCentralWidget(webView)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's similar to the behavior of a standard web browser: you cannot select part of text in a text hyperlink. I'm not sure on how the internal PDF viewer works for Chromium, but, if it's a standard HTML/js component (just like PDF.js) this probably means that the only way to do that is by injecting a javascript and prevent mouse button interaction. In any case, you cannot directly do that from the Qt API.

Comment: I have used PDF.js as well. If I want to prevent the mouse button interaction there, would I have to make changes in the viewer.js file?

Comment: Probably, yes. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31053948) or [this issue on github](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10664).

Comment: The answer in the first link seems to have the solution. Unfortunately the place where a code has to be inserted no longer exists in pdfjs-3 and I can't find the appropriate place in the current viewer.js